# how to pass another google form google sheet value to another google form textbox value

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

i created two google form with two google sheets . one form for participants, and second form for department head to fill details about participant. participants form ask to fill their name, email, designation, and other questioners and end of the form need enter their head of the department email address. [form for participants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS6dD.png)
heads side form looks like following. it ask about the participant that related to his department.
[Form for department head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6kra.png)

my problem is when some employee fill the form to participate to a program after submit his form i want to send the email about his request to the head of the department that the above employee mentioned in his form. and that email should include the link to Form of the "report of the department head". then when the head of the department click on that link i want to automatically fill the "Name of the participants " box in that heads form. then he can fill the other information and can submit heads report form. (unless head of the department should enter his department member name manually. some of the head of the department not supported to do that.)

Answer (score 0):

the [Form Workflow Plus](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/form_workflow_plus_addon/448262164641) Google Forms add-on does exactly that. Only caveat is that it is a paid add-on.